# Updating an asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an asp.net web service that passes Entity objects back and forth. I changed my database schema to accept `NULL` for a certain column that didn't before. I updated my entity model to reflect this. I ran "Update service reference" on the service reference in the WS client project, and then I recompiled the whole lot. But when I try to send an object with NULL in that field, it gives me `"This property cannot be set to a null value"`. Using the debugger, I see it never even sends it to the WS server. It gets blocked already at the WS client. How do I update this to reflect my change that allows `NULL`?

Comment: Are you sure your entity model is correctly updated? It seems like something is not really updated. Just to be sure - try to remove the entire model and generate it from the beginning (do not update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986143/entity-framework-designer-not-updating-conceptual-model) question, I found that it seems to be a bug in VS2010. Following a comment there, I removed and re-added the table to the model (wasn't a big deal in my case) and that solved it.